# javaFx table is not populating though everything seems fine

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, scenebuilder

I know this question has answers here, Still I dont find why my table is not updating values .

Here is my codes...

I have used this class as table data type,

```
package demo;

public class Doctor {

   private String name;
   private String dept;
   private String salary;
   private String phone;

   public Doctor() {
   }

   public Doctor(String n, String d, String s, String p) {
       name = n;
       dept = d;
       salary = s;
       phone = p;
   }
}
```

This is my FXML code of The controller class

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import java.util.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="698.0" prefWidth="526.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="demo.DoctorController">
       <children>
        <AnchorPane layoutX="4.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="498.0" prefWidth="530.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
             <children>
                <TableView fx:id="doctorsTable" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="197.0" prefWidth="509.0">
                  <columns>
                    <TableColumn fx:id="docNameCol" editable="false" prefWidth="124.0" text="NAME" />
                    <TableColumn fx:id="docDeptCol" prefWidth="102.0" text="DEPT." />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="docSalaryCol" prefWidth="98.0" text="SALARY" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="docPhoneCol" prefWidth="167.0" text="PHONE" />
                  </columns>
                </TableView>
                <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="34.0" text="LIST OF ALL THE DOCTORS(S)" />
                <ListView fx:id="doctorList" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="363.0" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="264.0" />
                <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="298.0" text="SELECT A DOCTOR TO SEE THEIR APPOINTMENTS WITH THEIR PATIENTS" />
                <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="325.0" text="LIST OF PATIENTS:" />
                <Label layoutX="198.0" layoutY="602.0" text="Label">
                   <font>
                      <Font size="72.0" />
                   </font>
                </Label>
             </children>
          </AnchorPane>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

And This is my Controller class...

```
    package demo;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

    public class DoctorController implements Initializable {
        @FXML
        private TableView<Doctor> doctorsTable;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Doctor, String> docNameCol;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Doctor, String> docDeptCol;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Doctor, String> docSalaryCol;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Doctor, String> docPhoneCol;
        @FXML
        private ListView<String> doctorList;


        private Connection con;
        private Statement stat;
        private ResultSet res;
        private String query;
        private String fname;
        private String fdept;
        private String fsalary;
        private String fphone;


        DatabaseConnection dbobj = new DatabaseConnection();


        private void connect() throws SQLException{
            con=dbobj.getConn();
            stat=dbobj.getState();
        }

        private void init(){
            docNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
            docDeptCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dept"));
            docSalaryCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salary"));
            docPhoneCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("phone"));
        }



        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
               init();
            try {
                populateTable();
                System.out.println("items added");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoctorController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        }

        private void populateTable() throws SQLException{
            ObservableList<Doctor> tableVlues = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            connect();
            query = "Select * from Doctor";
            res = stat.executeQuery(query);
            tableVlues.add(new Doctor());
            while(res.next()){
                fname = res.getString("doctorName");
                fdept = res.getString("doctorDept");
                fsalary = res.getString("doctorSalary");
                fphone = res.getString("doctorPhone");
                System.out.println(fname+", "+fdept+" , "+fsalary+" , "+fphone);  // This line prints everything correctly
                tableVlues.add(new Doctor(fname, fdept, fsalary, fphone));
                list.add(fname+", "+fdept+" , "+fsalary+" , "+fphone);
            }
            doctorList.setItems(list);
            doctorsTable.setItems(tableVlues);
        }

    }
```

My Db connection is ok. Beside, I tried to store the fetched items into the ListView. And this works perfectly. But it is not working with the TableView.
What am I doing wrong ? Please Help.

Comment: You have `getXXX()` methods defined in the `Doctor` class that you are not showing, right?

Comment: No, I havent defined any get or set method inside Doctor.java .

Comment: Is it necessary to populate Tableview

Comment: If you use a `PropertyValueFactory`, yes. See [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html).

Comment: Ok, Thank you James. :)
Btw, is there any alternative of PropertyValueFactory ?

Comment: You can implement the appropriate `Callback` yourself... You would have to be able to access the values though, so you would need some kind of accessor method in the model class anyway.